# What is the value of $P(A \cap B\ |\ C)$?

Tags: probability

> Let $A,B,C$ be three events such that $P(A)=0.4,P(B)=0.5,P(A \cup B)=0.6,P(C)=0.6$ and $P(A \cap B \cap C^c)=0.1$. Then $P(A \cap B\ |\ C)$ is equal to
>
> $(1)$ $\frac {1} {2}.$
>
> $(2)$ $\frac {1} {3}.$
>
> $(3)$ $\frac {1} {4}.$
>
> $(4)$ $\frac {1} {5}.$

**My attempt** $:$

We know that $A \cap B = (A \cap B\ |\ C) \cup (A \cap B\ |\ C^c)$. Let $E=(A \cap B\ |\ C)$ and $F=(A \cap B\ |\ C^c)$. Then clearly $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive events. So $P(A \cap B) = P(E)+P(F).$  We have to find out $P(E).$

Now $P(E) = P(A \cap B) - P(F) = P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cup B) - \frac  {P(A \cap B \cap C^c)} {P(C^c)}=0.4+0.5-0.6 - \frac {0.1} {0.4}=0.3-0.25=0.05=\frac {1} {20}.$

Which does not equal to any of the options given above. What are my mistakes? Please help me in showing my misconceptions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It should be
$$A \cap B = (A \cap B \cap C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C^c)$$

Guide:

First find $P(A \cap B)$.

Then find $P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap B \cap C^c)$

Then find $P(A \cap B|C)$ using definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So $(2)$ is the correct option.

Answer (score 2):

$E$ and $F$ are not mutually exclusive events; there not even events.

One good idea is to compute $P(A \cap B)$:

$$\frac{6}{10} = P(A \cup B)  =P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \frac{9}{10} - P(A \cap B)$$

and it follows that $P(A \cap B) = \frac{3}{10}$.

The law of total probabilities says in this case:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap B | C)P(C) + P(A \cap B| C^c)P(C^c)$$

as $C$ and $C^c$ are mutually exclusive events. Hence $P(C^c) = 1-P(C)$

Also by definition:

$$P(A \cap B | C^c)= \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C^c)}{P(C^c)}$$

Now you know all necessary values to solve for $P(A \cap B|C)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can get $$ P(A\cap B)=0.3$$ from the usual formula.

Then we have $$ P(A\cap B|C) = \frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}.$$

And finally we have that $$P(A\cap B \cap C) + P(A\cap B\cap C^c) = P(A\cap B) $$

Combining these three equations with the known values gives one of the answers.

Your problem has origin in your first step when you wrote $$A\cap B = (A\cap B|C)\cup (A\cap B| C^c).$$ This makes no sense as $(A\cap B|C)$ is not an event. Instead you want $$A\cap B = (A\cap B\cap C) \cup (A\cap B\cap C^c).$$ Which, together with the fact that the two events whose union we take on the RHS are disjoint, gives my third equation